# Enabling SSH for deploy of a bitbucket git repo

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I'm trying to deploy my git repo to my server. To make this work I first needed to setup ssh on my locale computer and on my server.

for bitbucket I followed https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html and for pm2 I followed https://keymetrics.io/2014/06/25/ecosystem-json-deploy-and-iterate-faster/

I created the pub/priv key on my own computer and on my server. The connection now works since I can login to the server without entering a password. For the server I followed the exact same steps, but every time I reconnect to the server I got the error

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
```

I figured out that the ssh-agent was offline everytime I reconnected and therefore `ssh-add -l` wouldn't print any result. I now added at the end of `.bashrc`

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Which seems to work, but always prompts me for the passphrase of `.ssh/id_rsa`

which probably is the reason why a `pm2 deploy production setup` from my locale machine returns:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Cloning into '/home/myuser/myproject/source'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

  failed to clone
```

has anyone an idea what I did wrong?

**edit:** I found this great answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869 I decided to download keychain and added

```
eval `keychain --eval id_rsa`
```

instead of the old 2 commands to my `.bashrc`. Now I can login to my server without any warning or error and `ssh-add -l` displays my key correctly. but on my locale machine the `pm2` command throws exactly the same error. Can the problem be somewhere else?

**SOLUTION**

I just redid the whole process with the same result. Finally I added the `eval`keychain --eval id_rsa`` line at the top of my `.bashrc` file. Now cloning works perfectly. I'm still not sure why the position within the file matters, but anyway.. it works